# Не обновляется виджет QLabel вновь добавленными данными

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlabel, show

У меня есть функция, которая достает из списка данные и выводит их в качестве `QLabel` на экран. 
Работает хорошо без проблем выводит все элементы на экран, но когда в список добавляется новый элемент, я не могу обновить/вызвать ещё раз свою функцию чтобы на экране отобразились новые элементы. 
Только если я перезапущу программу.

Если кто-то знает решение, подскажите, буду благодарен!

```
    ...
    self.t_show_all_houses = QTimer(self)
    self.t_show_all_houses.timeout.connect(self.show_all_houses)
    self.t_show_all_houses.start(2000)


    def show_all_houses(self):
        for get_house in house.db_house:
            x_position = int(get_house[5])
            y_position = int(get_house[6])
            id = str(get_house[0])
            column_name =  str(id) + '_label_name'
            #print(x_position,y_position)
            self.column_name = QLabel(self)
            self.column_name.resize(150, 150)
            self.column_name.move(x_position, y_position)
            self.column_name.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-image: url('images/house150x150.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;}");
    
    self.show_all_houses()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Нет смысла переменную `column_name` делать атрибутом класса.

Чтобы показать вновь созданный экземпляр виджета,
вам надо либо добавить его в менеджер компоновки,
либо показать этот вновь созданный виджет:

```
column_name.show()
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.spinBox_x = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox_x.setRange(0, 500)
        self.spinBox_x.setSingleStep(50)
        self.spinBox_x.setProperty("value", 300)
        self.spinBox_y = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox_y.setRange(0, 500)
        self.spinBox_y.setSingleStep(50)
        self.spinBox_y.setProperty("value", 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить запись')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_record)
        
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox_x, 1, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox_y, 1, 1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 3)

        self.t_show_all_houses = QTimer(self)
        self.t_show_all_houses.timeout.connect(self.show_all_houses)
        self.t_show_all_houses.start(2000)

# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.house_db_house = [                    # <---- house.db_house
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
            [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 150, 150],
        ]
        self.show_all_houses()

    def show_all_houses(self):
        for get_house in self.house_db_house:      # <---- house.db_house
            x_position = int(get_house[5])
            y_position = int(get_house[6])
            id = str(get_house[0])
# ???            column_name =  str(id) + '_label_name'

#           self.column_name = QLabel(self)
#           ...
# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            column_name = QLabel(f'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n   {id}_label_name', self.widget)
            column_name.resize(150, 150)
            column_name.move(x_position, y_position)
            column_name.setStyleSheet("""
                QLabel {
                    background-image: url('images/head.jpg');
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-position: center;
                    background-color: #ff5652;
                }
            """)
            column_name.show()                                           # !!! +++
            
    def add_record(self):
        new_id = self.house_db_house[-1][0] + 1
        x_position = self.spinBox_x.value()
        y_position = self.spinBox_y.value()        
        self.house_db_house.append([new_id, 2, 3, 4, 5, x_position, y_position])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**head.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!